# Enquire.js does not match initially, only on resize

Tags: javascript, media-queries, vue.js, enquire.js

I'm doing media queries with [*Enquire.js*](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js) and *Vue.js*. It all pretty much works when I resize the browser's window manually. However, I get no match on document load, an odd behavior that is most obvious when switching *Chrome's toggle device mode* on or when accessing the site on a mobile phone. I checked with the ["Match & Unmatch Example"](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/examples/match-unmatch/), and it works as expected in said mode or when accessing it with a mobile phone. I wonder if there's some sort of incompatibility between *Vue.js* and *Enquire.js* or am I doing something wrong?

The logic for the media queries is on my vue instance's ready hook:

```
ready:
    function () {
        var self = this;
        enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 400px)", {
            match: function () {
                self.displayIsLarge = false;
                self.displayIsSmall = true;
            },
            unmatch: function () {
                self.displayIsLarge = true;
                self.displayIsSmall = false;
            }
        })
    );
```

On my vue instance, I've the following data properties:

```
var menu = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    displayIsLarge: true,
    displayIsSmall: false,
```

On my html file, I'm using `v-if="displayIsSmall"` and `v-if="displayIsLarge"` to hide/display elements according to the browser's size. JsdFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/932fu9ox/16/).

It came to my mind in the meanwhile, that I might be able to solve this issue with the `Setup` callback, perhaps with a conditional, something like this:

```
enquire.register("screen and (max-width: 400px)", {
    setup: function() {
        if (this.match) {
            self.displayIsSmall = true;
        }
        else {
            self.displayIsSmall = false;
        }
    },
    match: function () {
        self.displayIsLarge = false;
        self.displayIsSmall = true;
    },
    unmatch: function () {
        self.displayIsLarge = true;
        self.displayIsSmall = false;
    }
})
```

This is not working as expected. What am I missing? JsdFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/932fu9ox/15/).

---

**UPDATE**

No luck either with Vue's [beforeCompile](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/932fu9ox/20/) or [created](http://jsfiddle.net/pierrebonbon/932fu9ox/22/) hooks (instead of `ready`).

Comment: The first fiddle you posted is working for me.  What is the problem for you? It switches when that pane of JSFiddle is 400px wide. Actually both of them are working for me

Comment: @Jeff the problem is that it is not matchin/unmatching the document size on page load. Meaning that in the JsFiddles above, it matches or umatches the pane size only when we manually resize it.

Comment: The `unmatch` only happens if you go from `match` to `unmatch`, it doesn't happen if you start in `unmatch` You should probably approach this mobile first and set `isSmallScreen` to `true` then change you query to `min-width` then switch them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `unmatch` only happens if you go from `match` to `unmatch`. Therefore it won't happen till you go under 400px then back over it. I recommend you take a mobile first approach and do something like this instead.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    displayIsLarge: false,
    displayIsSmall: true
  },
  ready: function () {
    var self = this;
    enquire.register("screen and (min-width: 400px)", {
        match: function () {
            self.displayIsLarge = true;
            self.displayIsSmall = false;
        },
        unmatch: function () {
            self.displayIsLarge = false;
            self.displayIsSmall = true;
        }
    })
  }
})
```

Here's a small demo: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/uc7gaec0/

Though, depending on what these elements are actually containing and/or doing it probably makes more sense to just toggle them visually with CSS. You know what's going on better than me, though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping that this was it, but when I turn `Chrome device mode` on, it doesn't produce the intended result. On page load, or when I resize the browser's window manually, it works as intended. See [here for when it is large](https://gyazo.com/46ed7c337ec9aaaa3187de3bc45a44ef) and [here for when it is small](https://gyazo.com/3bd972a445c583926bf049372ee34cba). However, when I turn `Chrome device mode` [on, with a 320px-wide device](https://gyazo.com/fd8655d759cd95b9eaacfee54ed45b33), it doesn't toggle to small as it should.

Comment: The screen shots aren't super helpful without code. Just to be clear though, nothing inside `unmatch` will happen unless `match` happens first. So you can resize that all you want under 400px and that `unmatch` will never fire unless you go from over 400px to under it again.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Still, don't get it why this code is turning a `match` when the browser loads (as well as on resize), if the browser's window is less than 400px wide, while the same thing doesn't happen when Chrome's `toggle device mode` is on (or when accessing the page from a mobile phone).

Comment: I totally forgot about some css properties that needed to be changed accordingly... I will accept your answer given that I now get a `match` when the page loads, whereas before I had to resize the window before anything happened. Thanks again!

Comment: This should hopefully clear it the situation a bit: https://jsfiddle.net/crswll/uc7gaec0/1/

Comment: Hi, thanks for the new JsFiddle! I think it's lacking some html though ;-)

Comment: It just needs console.log(). Shows how, when things are called.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to making sure I got a `match` on page load and not only after a resize (as detailed in the above answer), I had to add a `<meta>` viewport tag in my `index.html`. Adding the following metatag for instance will force the viewport to scale to the device's dimensions, now rendering the correct style (i.e., mobile):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

The `width=device-width` will make an equivalence between the width of page to that of the device, whereas `initial-scale=1` will set the initial zoom when the pages loads.

More details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag).